# XML serialization in WPF - very long XML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xml-parsing

I have a big string that I get from the system (OTA) that contain all the users in the system.

The string is very long ( if I save it as a file it's about 9MB), and when I try to load it to xml I get:
`"Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long."`**(XDocument)**

OR

`"hexadecimal value 0x14, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 604946"` **(XMLDocument)**

I need only the users name from this XML (string) someone have an idea for a workaround or something?

Comment: Use `XmlTextReader` to read XML one element at the time.

Comment: Hell XML is just text. If nothing works - parse by hand (read a stream , remember the things between your user start and end tag and thats it)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to load your document using `Load(string)` where the string is the document uri. Try using the static method `Parse` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use serialization with a stream to get over the problem of the file size :) 10x for all the helpers :)